# J2ME Commends Order 

Tags: java, java-me

I have mixed some different types of command like OK,CANCEL,BACK,EXIT,SCREEN in my application.

For Example,

```
exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 5);
_123=new Command("123",Command.BACK,4);
ABC=new Command("ABC",Command.CANCEL,3);
sample1=new Command("Sample1",Command.SCREEN,1);
sample2=new Command("Sample2",Command.OK,2);
```

The Order i need is :Sample1,Sample2,ABC,Exit. But it Display like this Sample1,Sample2,Exit,ABC are right side and 123 is placed in left side button.

Here, I also have one problem while adding one more command(Edit_Cell) using like below.... and also i need to display in the first place before Sample1.But it displayed in End of all the commands on right hand side.

I have added this new Command(Edit_Cell) in another src file constructor and call that constructor in below of my above code(adding commands).

Edit_Cell is type of SCREEN and PRIORITIES IS 1 on the other source file.

My Final Order i need is : `Edit_Cell,Sample1,Sample2,ABC,Exit, on right hand side and _123` on left hand side.

Comment: what environment you are using ? I meant which IDE & WTK particularly ?

Comment: i am not using any ide.i am using only sun java wireless tool kit 2.5.2. cldc 1.1 and midp2.0

Comment: Personally I would suggest go for NetBeans for this env. it will give you visual designer , so no need to worry about core designer code

Comment: you are absolutely correct.but my application is in deliverable stage(final stage and fully developed without using netbeans)That's i raised this question.Please help me...

Comment: This kind of questions is very usefull to j2me and mobile application developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reply to your comment here, it's less messy...
Maybe it's displaying the commands in the same order they were added (not using priorities). I would delete all commands when `Edit_Cell` is added and add them all again, after `Edit_Cell` is added.
If you can only modify your form's code, then you can override the `addCommand` method to ensure when `Edit_Cell` is added all previous commands are removed and added again later.

Something like this:

```
@Override
    public void addCommand(Command cmd) {
        if (cmd.getLabel().equals("Edit_Cell")){
           removeCommand(sample1); // with all the previously added commands
        }
        super.addCommand(cmd);
        if (cmd.getLabel().equals("Edit_Cell")){
          addCommand(sample1); // again with all your previously added commands
        }
    }
```

It's not very elegant, but well, you can always make it more classy, as long as it works....

Answer (score 5):

First of all, and without offense, I think you should elaborate a bit more your written compositions, it took me a while to understand the issue.

Still, the way you claim commands makes sense according to this (Nokia's wiki forum):

> The Command mapping to softkeys follow following rules:
>
> **Right softkey**: There can be only one
>   "negative" Command (STOP, CANCEL,
>   BACK, EXIT in this priority order)
>   mapped to Right softkey, and the
>   Command mapped there is directly
>   invoked by softkey press.
>
> **Left softkey**: Mutiple commands can be
>   mapped under Left softkey in which
>   case there is "Options" label in Left
>   softkey and selection of it will open
>   a menu of commands. If there's however
>   only a single "positive" Command (OK,
>   ITEM, SCREEN or HELP) under left
>   softkey it will be presented directly
>   on Left softkey. (Note: Some LCDUI
>   components have their own operations
>   that will be also visible under left
>   softkey thus forcing Options menu.) If
>   there's more than one negative Command
>   this will force Options menu on Left
>   softkey and the commands will be
>   presented in the order define below.
>
> **Middle softkey**: In Series 40 only a
>   single context sensitive Command (OK,
>   ITEM) is mapped to Middle softkey. In
>   S60 multiple context sensitive
>   Commands (OK, ITEM) can be mapped to
>   Middle Softkey. If there's only single
>   Command it will be shown directly in
>   softkey, otherwise commands are
>   visible in context sensitive menu
>   opened from middle softkey. Normally
>   the same commands mapped to Middle
>   softkey are also available in Left
>   softkey (directly or via Options
>   menu). Note: Some UI components
>   override this rule and place component
>   specific operation directly to Middle
>   softkey. For example, POPUP
>   ChoiceGroup has "Open" operation in
>   Middle softkey.

Obviously this depends a lot on the platform, but it seems your midlet is assuming `_123` as the negative Command, and all others are placed on the other soft key.

I would try to change the types and set the priorities as you wish... something like this

```
exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 5);
_123=new Command("123",Command.BACK,0);
ABC=new Command("ABC",Command.SCREEN,3);
sample1=new Command("Sample1",Command.SCREEN,1);
sample2=new Command("Sample2",Command.OK,2);
```

And you can set the priority of `Edit_Cell` to 0 and its type to `SCREEN`. And just to add: `ITEM` commands are usually placed before.

I hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.U have modified ABC=new Command("ABC",Command.CANCEL,3); AS ABC=new Command("ABC",Command.SCREEN,3);But i want that cancel type and keep the same order. Please give me a solution...

Comment: if the platform places CANCEL commands after SCREEN commands, there isn't much you cand do, and since the type of command is only for key mapping and placement of the command, I suggest you do do that. You either lose the Cancel Key mapping (if you actually got it) or accept how the platform place your CANCEL commands. It's up to your priorities.

Comment: exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 5);
_123=new Command("123",Command.BACK,0);
ABC=new Command("ABC",Command.CANCEL,3);
sample1=new Command("Sample1",Command.SCREEN,1);
sample2=new Command("Sample2",Command.OK,2); But it displays like this.,Sample1,Sample2,Exit,ABC,Edit_Cell. But i need the following order Edit_Cell,Sample1,Sample2,ABC,Exit. Please consider Edit_Cell declared in another source file and added in this form at runtime...
Expecting your valuable reply and thanks for taking more time for me...

Comment: Change ABB to SCREEN (I explained it on my previous reply). Set the priorities Sample1 to 2, Sample2 to 3 and ABC to 4.

Comment: OKEY, thanks, But Still Edit_Cell placed in the last.Didn't become first place. What i do?